How to create a Graph based on user input in ORACLE APEX using SQL Queries
I am trying to write an SQL query in Oracle Apex that accesses items in the page and then creates a graph based on that item. In this case, I want to display the last 5 games of a player that the user inputs.
I have tried using v('P2_PLAYER') and :P2_PLAYER to access the item value, but it still does not work; my graph returns no data.
Here is the code I am using currently (it works when I simply put PLAYER = 'Caitlin Clark', or any player in the database rather than PLAYER = :P2_PLAYER)
SQL Statement
Page

P2_PLAYER looks like a select list item. If that's so, usually its query looks like
select player_name as display_value,
       player_id   as return_value
from players
order by player_name

which means that

what you see on the screen is Caitlin Clark, but
what item really contains is 7369 (Caitlin's ID)

So, if your graph query works OK when you use her name in where clause:
where player = :P2_PLAYER

then

fix select list item's query so that it returns player name, or
modify graph's query so that it uses player's ID (instead of a name)


Certainly, as you didn't share info that might be relevant for this problem, what I wrote is just a guess based on what we usually do. See if it helps. If not, edit the question and provide some more details.

What is the flow ? Without specifying how you want the page to work - what is rendered, what the user is doing and what the expected behaviour is - this question is impossible to answer.
So I'm assuming...that the page is rendered and then the user selects a value for P2_PLAYER. In that case you would create an on-change dynamic action on P2_PLAYER that refreshes the "region that creates the graph". Make sure to enter P2_PLAYER in the "items to submit" attribute of that region to ensure the current session state of the items in taken into account when the region is rendered. If this doesn't work provide more info.
